# Python. Как данные из XML передать в массив и записать изменеия в таблицу БД MySQL?

Tags: python, xml

Прошу помочь передать данные из XML-файла в массив и передать данные из этого массива в таблицу БД MySQL.
test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <Result RC="0" /> 
        <Invoices>
            <Invoice Invoice_ID="12123" Invoice_Owner_ID="232" ICN_ID="2321" ICN_Owner_ID="321" Receipt_Date="15.12.2016"> 
              <Receiver CompanyName="com1" ContactName="name1" Address="adr1" /> 
              <Shipper CompanyName="com2" Address="adr2" /> 
            </Invoice>
            <Invoice Invoice_ID="23232" Invoice_Owner_ID="32" ICN_ID="3213" ICN_Owner_ID="32" Receipt_Date="15.12.2016"> 
              <Receiver CompanyName="com3" ContactName="name2" Address="adr3" /> 
              <Shipper CompanyName="com4" Address="adr4" /> 
            </Invoice>
            <Invoice>
               ............
            </Invoice>

        </Invoices>
    </root>
```

test.py

```
Начало скрипта    

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml") 
root = tree.getroot()


for elem in root.iter('Invoice'):
    invoice_id = elem.get('Invoice_ID')
    invoice_owner_id = elem.get('Invoice_Owner_ID')
    icn_id = elem.get('ICN_ID')
    icn_owner_id = elem.get('ICN_Owner_ID')
    receipt_date = elem.get('Receipt_Date')
    print(invoice_id, invoice_owner_id, icn_id, icn_owner_id, receipt_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен обычный массив? Если да, то вот:

```
    myArray = []
    for elem in root.iter('Invoice'):
        invoice_id = elem.get('Invoice_ID')
        invoice_owner_id = elem.get('Invoice_Owner_ID')
        icn_id = elem.get('ICN_ID')
        icn_owner_id = elem.get('ICN_Owner_ID')
        receipt_date = elem.get('Receipt_Date')
        print(invoice_id, invoice_owner_id, icn_id, icn_owner_id, receipt_date)
        myArray.append({'Invoice_ID':invoice_id, 'Invoice_Owner_ID':invoice_owner_id, 'ICN_ID':icn_id, 'ICN_Owner_ID':icn_owner_id, 'Receipt_Date':receipt_date})
```

Таким образом вы получаете массив словарей, к которым можно обращаться так например:

```
invoice = myArray[1]['Invoice_ID']
```

Comment: выдает:  IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: А, понял! Извините, спутал с другим языком.
Сейчас изменю ответ.

Comment: Поправил ответ :)

Comment: Спасибо, @michael .